# it does not return the drawableId using the title in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable

I am using this structure to return the Id of the drawable. I imported my PNG to drawable and in the end it returns 0. That is, it can't find it. check the name and it is accurate. I need to know the cause.

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val drawableId = remember(name) {
    context.resources.getIdentifier(
        name,
        "drawable",
        context.packageName
    )
}
Image(
    painterResource(id = drawableId),
    contentDescription = "..."
)
```

Comment: have you tried getting image with the same name using `R.drawable.name`?

Comment: to be more explicit: I am creating a manual on echocardiography because I am a doctor. I have created a MenuDrawer and inside tabs to show as chapters of the manual. Since I don't know how to use PDF and some are paid, I chose to edit my own text and images. The text is in my string resources and the images are in my wadrable resources. Since I don't know any other way to format the text, I invented some markers to format the text and to save where to put my images...

Comment: . The text is inside a string-array. I use a function to process each of the string-arrays and it returns the formatted text or images. But for that I need to read the warable images using a string with their title. It works divinely for me with the first chapter but for the second it is not returning the ID of the images and I am sure that the titles are fine. it returns 0.

Comment: you may have some mistake in between, try logging `name` and checking whether `R.drawable.name` is available. Also are you using multiple modules?

Comment: I found the problem. When importing my images android does not support capital letters and I modify the title to all lowercase. That's why I couldn't find it